# Submit form from jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-events

I want to show a JQuery-UI dialog when I submit the form.
I have the code with me but I have the following ideas and want to know which would be the most ideal.

```
   var openDialog =function(){
      //set up dialog .
      var saveButton = // "OK" of dialog -> click event calls: submit the form
      var cancel = //  "Cancel" of dialog -> click event calls :close the dialog
   };
```

**METHOD 01**

Should I setup the form as:

```
$('form').submit(function(evt){
   openDialog();
});
```

**Doubt**

If I do this and call `form.submit()` when the saveButton is clicked wont the `openDialog` called again this would create a cycle.

**OR**

**METHOD 02**

Should I setup a click on the submit button `/link` in the form to call `openDialog()` and with submit as well.
How would I call `form.submit()` when the "Ok" button of confirm is clicked without triggering the submit event setup on the form.

**Edit: I would appreciate it if this could be answered as well**

This being said. If I have ASP.NET MVC Data Annotations setup on the form. How can set up the script such that the dialog opens up only if the MicrosoftValidations are run. I am using ASP.MVC 3.0 and not using jQuery Validation/Validator.

**BottomLine:**
How do I setup a dialog such that I get the modal dialog when one tries to submit a form?

Answer (score 1):

A graceful degradation approach. Off the top of my head...

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" text="Submit" />
</form>
```

```
$("#submit").click(function ()
{
    // open dialog here

    return false;
});
```

If JavaScript is disabled, the form will simply submit. But if JavaScript is enabled, the click-event on the submit button (in the form) will open a dialog and prevent the form from submitting. What you need to do now is attach a click-event on the "OK" button in the dialog, and submit the form from there...

```
$("#dialog_submit").click(function ()
{
    $("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: What about the case when javascript is enabled and the user submits the form by hitting Enter/Return. there would not be a dialog shown in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Add preventDefault() to not submit the form so you can submit it later, with the dialog

```
$('form').submit(function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault();
   openDialog();
   // I think return false should work too
   return false;
});
```

Edit : ok there is a infinite loop
To avoid this you must submit the form in the openDialog with :

```
$('form')[0].submit()
```

In this case submit event is not triggered (tested in Safari)

```
$().ready(function()
{
$('form').submit(function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault();
   openDialog();
   // I think return false should work too
   return false;
})
})

function openDialog()
{
    if(confirm("ok ?"))
        $('form')[0].submit()       
    else
        alert('form not submitted')
}
```

Comment: This would satisfy that I will get a dialog opened when I try to submit the form.However my openDialog() has a "OK" button which calls form.submit() when you click it. Wont this trigger the openDialog() again.

Comment: You could just do `return confirm("Ok?")` in the form submit event. Also; I think that what friction wants his own custom dialog, not the standard JavaScript confirm dialog.

Comment: the confirm is just for example, you can do  you want